# cloning to set this object's properties through the constructor

Tags: c#

I have the following problem. I want to be able to set this to the passed reference without using reflection, can this be done?

```
//partial class of a Linq-to-SQL class 
public partial class Product
{
   public Product (Product product, List<ProductAttributes> productAttributes)
   {
      // without individually setting all the properties

      //then just set any other properties
      this.ProductAttributes = productAttributes;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set `this` in reference types (and setting it in value types is probably not something to be condoned). If what you're looking to do is a shallow (or deep) copy of the object's fields or properties, then you have two choices:

1. Manually
2. Reflection

Neither the language nor the runtime have any built-in facility for automating shallow or deep copying, and for good reason. It would be impossible to determine what that would look like for any given type.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, basically.

You can only set `this` in structs, and even then it's usually a bad idea :)

If you can explain what higher-level goal you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help more - but you simply *can't* change the value of `this` for a reference type, with or without reflection.

Comment: apologise I should of worded the question better, yes in c# you can't change a memory address this is read-only for all intense purposes. thank you for your feedback jon.

Comment: It should be noted that this is valid for all relaxed and unassuming purposes, as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign anything to `this` in a class as **it's read-only**.

I suspect you wanted to do so because of a bad design. You probably should post *what you actually want*, not *how you would like to do it* so we can provide a more appropriate answer.

Comment: well the problem is a result of a complex linq statement, where I'm stuck in a hole and I want to avoid further executing another statement. I knew it was impossible to set this = product and I really want to avoid reflection however you've got exhaust all options. cheers

Comment: @WadeJohnston Maybe you could update your question with all the details about your problem (and the associated code), I'm sure we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not possible to do magically. You either need to use reflection, or to write a method that manually does the copying. There are, of course, [multiple](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) [libraries](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) that can do this for you.